# which command line I should run to open Power Point, say, the seventh slide on the whole screen?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

Let's say I have a POWER POINT document named "trees" and I want to automatically open the seventh slide in it in the full-theater view (I mean the whole screen), which command line do I need to run?
My Power Point is 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need [PowerPoint Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=048DC840-14E1-467D-8DCA-19D2A8FD7485&displaylang=en) to do this.

According to [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/powerpoint/HA101538891033.aspx), you can open a presentation to the seventh slide like so:

```
"c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\PPTVIEW.exe" /N7 "Presentation.pptx"
```

The path may vary depending on which version of Windows you're running. PowerPoint Viewer 2007 lets you view presentations created in PowerPoint 97 and later.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Word, Excel and Powerpoint viewer are no longer available in Recent versions of Office.**

If you are still sticked with old versions, An improved version of @JohnT code:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office*"') do (
  set "name=%%~a" & set "ver=!name:~6,2!"
)
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office!ver!\pptview.exe" /N7 "Presentation.pptx"
```

Microsoft office installations have bad habit, if you have multiple installations it will install all in same directory. This batch file will auto-recognize the most updated version and open with it. This will do the reverse (Open with the most older one installed):

```
@echo off & setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office*"') do (
  set "name=%%~a" & set "ver=!name:~6,2!" & goto Continue
)
:Continue
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office!ver!\pptview.exe" /N7 "Presentation.pptx"
```